# Given is relations which you concatenate. They form sentence / specific word. What sentence / word you get?

Tags: logic, relations, propositional-calculus

$R_1$ means "is married with"

$R_2$ means "is the mother of"

$R_3$ means "is child of"

Describe the following relations on the set of all humans colloquially:

(i) $R_1 \circ  R_2$

(ii) $R_2 \circ R_1$

(iii) $R_2 \circ R_3$

(iv) $R_3 \circ R_2$

(v) $R_2 \circ R_1 \circ R_3$

---

No sure what is asked. I try like these:

(i) is married with mother of.. I think this mean father?

(ii) is mother of married with.. = Husband?

(iii) is mother of is child of.. = Grandmother?

(iv) is child of is mother of.. = Grandson?

(v) is mother of is married with is child of.. = no idea xd

There is maybe trick how understand this correct? I don't know I understand it good or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

Try using $x$, $y$, and $z$ (and a $w$ for the last one)  Also, draw a family tree.

For example, for i): $x$ is married to $y$, who is the mother of $z$ ... then $x$ is the husband of $z$. So, yes, you got that one correct!

ii) $x$ would be the mother of $y$ who is married to $z$ .. making $x$ the *mother-in-law* of $z$

OK .. can you try this for the others?